# Busemann function-like function in Riemannian manifold $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $1$-Lipschitz

Tags: riemannian-geometry, metric-geometry

With user10354138' comment, let me explain the setting (in the paper) :

Consider a Busemann function in Riemannian manifold $(
\mathbb{R}^n,d)$ with $\mathbb{Z}^n$-**isometric action** $\ast$ where $d$ is a Riemannian distance.

Further, $|\| x-y\| -d(x,y)|<c$ for all $x,\ y$ and some norm $\|\ \|$. Assume that a linear map $L$ is a support function of $\|\ \|$-unit ball. We define $$ B\colon\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R},\
 B(x) =\limsup_{d(y_0,y) \rightarrow
 \infty}\ (L(y)- d(x,y)) $$

where $L\colon \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a linear map and $y_0$ is any reference point.

Prove that $B$ is $1$-Lipschitz map

Proof : I have a proof about special case :

Here we have a level set $A = \{z \in \mathbb{R}^n | L(z)=n \}$
where $n\rightarrow \infty$. We assume that for $\varepsilon$, there
is $n$ s.t. $
 y_n,\ Y_n \in A$ and $$
| B(x)  - L(y_n) + d(x,y_n) |< \varepsilon $$

$$ |B(X) - L(Y_n) + d(X,Y_n) |< \varepsilon $$

\begin{align*} 0 &<_{{\rm assumption}}
 B(x)-B(X) \\&= d(X,Y_n) - d(x,y_n) +O(\varepsilon )
  \\&= d(X,A)-d(x,A)
\\&= d(X,A)- d(x,a),\ {\rm some}\ a\in A
\\&\leq d(X,a)-d(x,a) \\
&\leq  d(x,X)\end{align*}

Can we prove this in general ?

Comment: There must be more to $d$ any Riemannian distance in order for $B$ to be well-defined.

Comment: I believe that this is analysis problem. Sup of two 1-Lipschitz functions is 1-Lipschitz. This also works here.